# Django DoesNotExist - Matching Query doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I'm working on a Django(1.4) and Python (2.7) project in which I have a custom model for user to get loggedin.

Here's my model:
**from models.py:**

```
class User_table(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    emailid = models.EmailField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.TextField()
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # True means drive is available for delivery
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(AddedFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='profile')
    uploaded_document = models.ForeignKey(AddedFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='document')
    approval_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    login_try = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

And here's my view:
**From views.py:**

```
def mainlogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username, emailid=email)
        verify_password = ''
        try:
            verify_password = handler.verify(password, obj.password)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if verify_password is True:
            request.session['user_id'] = obj.id
            request.session['user_type'] = obj.user_type
            user_name = obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name
            request.session['user_name'] = user_name
            if not obj.approval_status:
                return HttpResponse('Your account is not confirmed by administration.')
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.login_try = 0
            obj.save()
            return redirect(home)
        else:
            try:
                obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username, emailid=email);
                if obj:
                    s = obj.login_try
                    s = s + 1
                    obj.login_try = int(s)

                    if int(obj.login_try) >= 3:
                        obj.login_try = 3
                    obj.save()
                    if int(obj.login_try) == 3:
                        id = obj.id
                        key = get_random_string(length=10)
                        reset_link = 'It seems you forgot password or someone is trying to login you account. This is your password reset link please do not share this with other ' + settings.EMAIL_URL + 'reset_password/' + str(
                            id) + ' key is : ' + str(key)
                        send_mail('Reset link', reset_link, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [obj.emailid, ])
                        obj.password = str(key)
                        obj.save()
                        return HttpResponse(
                            'It seems you forgot password or someone is trying to login you account.  Password Reset link has been sent to your email id')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
            return redirect(mainlogin)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error is  : ', e)
        return HttpResponse('An error has occurred.')
if request.method == "GET":
    try:
        return render(request, "login.html")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I try to log in it returns an error:

> (u'error is  : ', DoesNotExist('User_table matching query does not exist.',))

I ahve taken a look into the database and confirm that I have the record which I'm trying to get from the view, but it still through this error.

What can be wrong here?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is an issue with your indentation. It's hard to understand your code. I think the `except` that seems to be at the same level than the `if` actually pairs with the `try` that seems not to have `exception`. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

checklist:
1 not sure this kind of express is supported, i usually use `someModel.objects.filter(id="asdf").filter(email="qwe@gmail.com")`

2 no record matched

Are you sure something should match?  The docs say:

> get() raises a DoesNotExist exception if an object wasn’t found for
> the given parameters. This exception is an attribute of the model
> class. Example:

[django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get)

Comment: Hi @陈海栋, from where I can get the `id` because the user is not logged in.

Comment: that's just an example of querying sequentially not at a same function call
not sure if this work:
User_table.objects.get(user_name=username, emailid=email);
maybe u need :
User_table.objects.filter(user_name=username).filter(emailid=email)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the only specific record you can use Django shortcut `get_object_or_404()` 
If you don't have specific entry in a database then Django will raise 404 exception. 
If you want to explore more this topic [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)